# I can't get my button to appear in normal size

Tags: html, css

This is probably something stupid but I can't find the reason this is happening. At the bottom of my page, I have a button that triggers another page. It is appearing at extremely large and I can't figure out why. I tried moving it outside the content and container divs with no change so it can't be the CSS.

```css
/* responsive css */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* regular css */
body {
    background-color: #cc33ff;
    color: #99ffcc;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a:link{
    color: #990000;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#container { 
    margin-left: auto;    
    margin-right: auto;
    width:80%;
   }

#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 width: 78%;
 background-color: #ecbef8;
 color: #000040;
 padding: 10px;
}


#logo {
 text-align:center;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;

}
.center{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.centerText{
    text-align: center;
}
.nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #88FFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 2px sienna solid;
}
.games{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    margin-left: 40px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 3fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.games a:link{
    color: #490707;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    font-size: .60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 2px double #000040;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.style1 {font-size: 18px}

/* game specific css */
#battle {
    width: 78%;
    border: 0;
    min-height: 60vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50px repeat(2, 150px) 150px repeat(2, 50px) 75px 150px repeat(2, 30px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
#item1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;

}

#item5, #item4 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
}
#item12{
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 7;
}
#item13 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
    grid-row: 8;
}

#battleInstructions {
    width: 85%;
    border: 0;
    min-height: 40vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 300px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
#BIitem1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}
#BIitem5 {
    grid-column: 1 /span 3;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Michelle's Arcade | Battle Instructions</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <img src="../images/funny-dragon.jpg" class="center" />
    <h1 class = "centerText">Michelle's Arcade </h1>
    <h2 class ="centerText"><em> Play a Game!</em></h2>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="flex flex1"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></div>
    <div class="flex flex2"><a href="../assets/about.html">About Michelle</a></div>
    <div class="flex flex3"><a href="../assets/play_games.html">Play a Game</a></div>
  </div> <!-- end nav -->
  </div> <!-- end container -->
    
  <div id="content">
      <div id="battleInstructions">
        <div id="BIitem1"><p><span class="style1">In this game you will battle the evil troll.
            You can choose your weapon from the three shown -- a set of magic rocks that are a lot stronger and
            heavier than they look, an extremely sharp sword, or a crossbow and arrow. Unfortunately, you do not 
            know ahead of time what weapon the troll will use. You each begin with 100 points. For each round of 
            the battle, the winner takes 10 points from the loser. When either of you reaches 200 points, the
            battle is over and one of you will lie dead. The winner is determined by the list shown below. Push 
            the button when you are ready to begin the battle and ... Good luck!</span></p></div>
        <div id="BIitem2"><p><span class="style1">Wizard</span></p>
            <p><img src="../images/wizard.jpg" width="120" height="168"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="BIitem3"><p><span class="style1">Troll</span></p>
            <p><img src="../images/troll.jpg" width="120" height="168"></p>
            </div>
        <div id="BIitem4"><span class="style1"><p>Weapons</p>
            <p><img src = "../images/rock.jpg" width="100" height="70" />&nbsp;Magic Rocks</p>
            <p><img src = "../images/sword.jpg" width="100" height="70" />&nbsp;Sword</p>
            <p><img src = "../images/arrow.jpg" width="100" height="70" />&nbsp;Bow & Arrow</p></div>
        <div id="BIitem5"><span class="style1">Note: <br />
              The rocks can deflect the arrow. <br />
              The sword beats the rocks. <br />
              The arrow beats the sword.</span></div>
      </div><!-- end battle instructions -->
      <input type="button" id="battle" value="Begin the battle!" onclick="location.href = 'battleground.html'";>
    </div> <!-- end content -->
    
    <div id="footer">Copyright &copy; 2018 Michelle's Arcade<br />
        <a href="mailto:dementeddwarf@gmail.com">dementeddwarf@gmail.com</a></div>
    </div> <!-- end footer -->
  </div> <!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you defined a big min-height and a big width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your battle button has a large width and min-height. 60vh means that it will use 60% of the vertical space of the entire screen.

```
#battle {
    width: 78%;
    border: 0;
    min-height: 60vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 50px repeat(2, 150px) 150px repeat(2, 50px) 75px 150px repeat(2, 30px);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

If you change the width to, say 400px, and the min-height to 150px it will shrink a lot.

Comment: But #battle is on a div on a different page. This div’s Id is battleInstructions. I did this one at 40 vh but moved the button outside all the divs so it only inherented from body and it was still big.

Comment: I removed the min-height from battleInstructions and it fixed it but I still don't understand why if I moved the input button out of that div (all divs) and to the bottom of the page where it should not be inheriting any styles, why was it still big.

Comment: That's because You're still referencing it in the stylesheet using the #id (#battle, or #battleInstructions). It doesn't matter where the tag is, in this case, since the width and height are absolute values.